# android why i can't retrieve a compressed bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap

here is what i do

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                        "/sdcard/Deltio1.jpg");
                Bitmap e = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                        imageData.length);
                e.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 65, out);
                out.close();
```

and to retrieve it

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/Deltio1.jpg");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
            Bitmap bitmap;
              bitmap = (Bitmap) in.readObject();
              ImageView photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.katagelia_photo);
              photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

It throws java.io.StreamCorruptedException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. But i leave it open for discussion and why the first one failed.

```
 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myJpgPath, options); 
 options.inSampleSize = 2;
```